# Xpage l18n of category

Tags: view, internationalization, xpages, categorization

I made resource bundle for translation. Everything was going well, except I cannot translate category in a view. Any ideas? (resource bundle is named "prevodi")

```
<xp:viewColumn id="translateThisSomehow" columnName="fl_company">
    <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader1" value="Company">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader></xp:viewColumn>

<xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn2">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:prevodi[rowVar.getColumnValues()[1]];}]]>
   </xp:this.value>
    <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader2" value="Employee">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

viewColumn2 works fine <- it isnt categorized

first viewColumn doesnt work <- categorized

Comment: I just wonder: when you translate view content - especially category - values will change their order, so users will be confused and will have hard times to find anything. Did you consider this?

Comment: This is specific problem. It havent occured to me this could happen. Good point to consider in future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a theory: I think the problem is about the lifecycle. View panel reads records to show categories but it seems like resource bundle is not ready yet. Instead of using computed value here, you might use converters;

```
<xp:viewColumn 
    id="translateThisSomehow" 
    columnName="fl_company">

    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:customConverter getAsObject="#{javascript:return value}">
            <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:return prevodi[rowVar.getColumnValues()[1]];}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
        </xp:customConverter>
    </xp:this.converter>


    <xp:viewColumnHeader 
        id="viewColumnHeader1" 
        value="Company">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

Comment: I thought of using csjs.. But this works like a charm!